# How to Log when anything is lazy-Loaded in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

Is there any possible way to Log when entities are lazy-loaded.

I am utilizing database first with Entity Framework 6. For it to be useful it would need to NOT log when retrieving (non-lazy) the initial entity(s) but only when Lazy-loading sub-entities. If the log had any of the following information it could be useful: raw sql for the Lazy-Load, what entity property was lazy-loaded, what line number in C# was the Lazy-Load triggered.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but other people might have the same issue as I did.

Looking at the [official EF documentation about logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception), I noticed that the lazy loading query in the sample was showing a parameter called `@EntityKeyValue1`. As all lazy loaded queries will require at least one key parameter, I assume that this one will always be present. So, I managed to log all lazy loaded queries the following way:

```
  Database.Log = s =>
  {
      if (s.Contains("@EntityKeyValue1"))
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"Lazy loading query: {s}");
      }
  };
```